# I don't understand $\limsup_n\:A_n$ in Probability Theory, why should it be equal to "infinitely many $A_n$ occur"?

Tags: probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf

The definition for limsup is:

## $$\bigcap _{n=1}^{\infty }\bigcup _{k=n}^{\infty }\:A_k$$

So this means that $$\left(A_1\cup \:A_2\cup \:A_3\cup \:...\right)\cap \left(A_2\cup \:\:A_3\cup \:\:...\right)\cap \:\left(A_3\cup \:\:\:...\right)\cap \:...$$ which is equal to the last element of this infinite sequence (let's call it $A_{\infty }$)

For example let $A_n\:=\:\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]$, then $$\left(A_1\cup \:A_2\cup \:A_3\cup \:...\right)\cap \left(A_2\cup \:\:A_3\cup \:\:...\right)\cap \:\left(A_3\cup \:\:\:...\right)\cap \:... = \left\{0\right\}$$ as $$\left[0,\frac{1}{\infty }\right]\:=\:\left[0,\:0\right]\:=\:\left\{0\right\}$$

The problem here with Probability Theory and its understanding of limsup is that we can create such kind of scenarios that "$A_{\infty }$" won't be equal to "ifinitely many $A_n$ occur".

For example let $A_{n}=\left\{\text{person number n wins the lottery}\right\}$, "$A_{\infty }$" (and thus $\limsup_n\:A_n$) would mean that the "last person of this infinite sequence will win the lottery", and not that "infinitely many $A_n$ occur" which is equal to "everyone wins" (as this is clearly not the case here, because only the $\infty$th person wins)

I really need help to understand this concept

Comment: There is no "last person" in an infinite sequence.

Comment: So what is the "solution" for $A_n\:=\:\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]$, then $\left(A_1\cup \:A_2\cup \:A_3\cup \:...\right)\cap \left(A_2\cup \:\:A_3\cup \:\:...\right)\cap \:\left(A_3\cup \:\:\:...\right)\cap \:...$ ? It's obvious that it's gonna be {0}, but this is in fact "the last element of an infinite sequence"

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to consider a harder example here - since your example of $A_n=[0,1/n]$ has lots and lots of special properties that make it a bit hard to generalize from (e.g. it's a nested sequence of compact sets).

Consider, for instance, the sequence (not worrying about non-unique decimal representations): $$A_n=\{x : \text{the }n^{th}\text{ decimal digit of }x\text{ after the decimal point is }7\}$$
Each of these sets is just some union of intervals, but the way they fit together is complicated - essentially, from a probabilistic point of view, these are independent events. Note that there is surely no "last" term in this sequence because there is no last place value in a decimal expansion.

Let's consider the $\limsup$ of this in parts. First, for any $n$, consider
$$(A_n\cup A_{n+1}\cup A_{n+2}\cup\ldots)$$
Literally, this is the set of $x$ such that there is a $7$ in the $n^{th}$ place after the decimal point or at the $(n+1)^{th}$ place or the $(n+2)^{th}$ or so on - otherwise said, it's the set of $x$ such that there is a $7$ somewhere at or after the $n^{th}$ place.

If you intersect these unions over all $n$, you get the $\limsup$, which then says, "The set of $x$ such that, for every $n$, there is a $7$ in the decimal expansion of $x$ either at or after the $n^{th}$ place."

This condition is the same as "infinitely many $7$'s". Note that if there were infinitely many $7$'s, there would have to be a $7$ after any $n$ places, because there could only have been finitely many $7$'s *before* that number of places. Conversely, if $x$ is in our $\limsup$, then there must be at least one place with a $7$, but there also must be another $7$ somewhere further down the line (by taking $n$ to be the place value after the first $7$) and another $7$ after that and so on - giving an infinite sequence of $7$'s. This reasoning generalizes to the idea that the $\limsup$ of a sequence of sets is the set of $x$ which are contained in infinitely many sets of that sequence.

Just to dispel any idea of "the infinite last term", you might want to consider the sequence $A_n=[1/{2n},1/n]$. You should note first that *no* term is in infinitely many of these sets - these are all sets of positive numbers, but $1/n$ will eventually be less than any positive number. You can see this from the $\limsup$ too: the union $(A_n\cup A_{n+1}\cup A_{n+2}\cup\ldots)$ is just equal to $(0,1/n]$ and then intersecting these over all $n$ gives the empty set. Note that, if you tried to say that the sequence had an imaginary "last term" or "limit" $A_{\infty}=[1/\infty,1/\infty]=[0,0]$, you would get the wrong answer - such notions have nothing to do with computing $\limsup$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such "last person". What we have is $A_i$ where $i=1,2,3,\dots$ (i.e. $i\in \mathbf Z_+$)

So in your example $\lim \sup A_n=\emptyset$.

**Understanding of $\lim\sup$:**

Let's say $a\in \lim \sup A_n=\bigcap_m\bigcup_{n\ge m} A_n$. That means $a$ occurs in $\bigcup_{n\ge m} A_n$ for every $m$. If $a$ doesn't occur in $A_1,A_2,\dots$ for infinite times, say, $a\in A_{i_1},A_{i_2},A_{i_3},\dots,A_{i_k}$. Then a large integer $m_0$ (large enough so that $m_0>i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k$) will lead to contradiction since $a\not\in \bigcup_{n\ge m_0} A_n$.

Comment: Ok now I see it, if x belongs to limsup A_n then x belongs to ( (1∪2∪3∪...)∩(2∪3∪...)∩(3∪...)∩) which means that x belongs to (1∪2∪3∪...) AND x belongs to (2∪3∪...) AND x belongs to (3∪...) etc. But still: x can theoretically only belong to A_infinity, to the very last element of this sequence (I know it doesn't exist but let's assume it). Why should x belong to A1, A2, A3, etc.?

Comment: Or is it because A_infinity does not exist then the only possiblity that "x belongs to (1∪2∪3∪...) AND x belongs to (2∪3∪...) AND x belongs to (3∪...)" will occur is if x belongs to A1, x belongs to A2, x belongs to A3, etc? But theoretically x does not have to belong to A1, and still this statement that "x belongs to (1∪2∪3∪...) AND x belongs to (2∪3∪...) AND x belongs to (3∪...)" will be true.....

Comment: Ah but still it would mean that "infinitely many An occur" in the end, guess I got it right now

Comment: If x belongs to lim sup A_n, we cannot guarantee that x belongs to A1, A2, A3, .... For example, if x only belongs to A2, A4, A6, A8, ...... then still x belongs to lim sup A_n. You can think carefully about what "infinitely many An" means.

Comment: And what would liminf mean in this place?

Comment: lim inf means "eventually". x belongs to lim inf A_n  if there is an integer N such that x belongs to A_i for every i >= N (e.g. N=100 and x belongs to A_100, A_101,A_102, A_103...)

Comment: So technically limsup and liminf could mean the same thing, as limsup is "infinitely many An" and liminf is "almost every An"? The only difference being that if limsup would result in x belonging to every An?

Comment: Not the same. Let's say x belongs to A2,A4,A6,.... Then x belongs to limsup but bot liminf. In fact, liminf A_n is a subset of limsup A_n (you can compare their definitions).

Comment: How should liminf be a subset of limsup if liminf is lets say A4, A5, A6, .. and limsup is A2, A4, A6, ... ? This does not make sense. Also, why is liminf defined as "x belongs to A_i for every i >= N", why not e.g. x belongs to A_i where i is even"?

Answer (score 1):

Use elements to understand it. Set $B_n:= \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty }A_k$ and note three things:

1. $\limsup_{n\to \infty }A_n= \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty }B_n$
2. $B_1 \supset B_2\supset \ldots \supset B_k\supset \ldots $, that is, the sequence of sets $(B_n)_n$ is decreasing.
3. Every $B_n$ is the union of infinitely many $A_k$.

Then if $x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty }B_n$ it means that $x\in B_n$ for all $n\in {\mathbb N}$. Now suppose that $x$ belongs only to a finite number of $A_k$, then as the $B_n$ are shrinking and they contains less and less $A_k$ each time then there is some $N\in {\mathbb N}$ such that $x\notin B_n$ for all $n\geqslant N$. This has shown that if $x$ belong to a finite number of $A_n$ then it cannot belong to $\limsup_{n\to \infty }A_n$, therefore if $x\in \limsup_{n\to \infty }A_n$ it necessarily belongs to an infinite number of $A_n$.

By the other hand if $x$ belongs to an infinite number of $A_n$ then $x\in B_n$ for all $n\in {\mathbb N}$, and so it belongs to the limit superior of the $A_n$. Then we had shown that $x\in \limsup_{n\to \infty }A_n$ if and only if $x$ belongs to infinitely many $A_n$.